# Multiple storyboards and view deallocation

Tags: ios, storyboard, dealloc

I developed an application using only one storyboard and towards the end, when my app grew to have some 80 views, working in the storyboard was extremely difficult.

After some clicks the storyboard became non responsive/sluggish and I had to restart the xcode to get things back to normal.

So this time I decided to use multiple storyboards but I have the following problem. When I switch from one storyboard to the other, views on the storyboard I am popping from are not deallocated. As a result instruments show a continuous increase in memory allocations which is not acceptable.

Anybody knows how to dealloc the view in the second storyboard when I move back to the first ?

Bellow are the two ways I use for navigation

With one storyboard

```
-(IBAction)goToVcSameStoryboard:(id)sender{

[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"segue" sender:self];
}

-(IBAction)backSameStoryboard:(id)sender{

[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

With two storyboards

```
-(IBAction)goToVcDiffStoryboard:(id)sender{
UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Storyboard1" bundle:nil];
        UIViewController *initialVC = [storyboard instantiateInitialViewController];
        initialVC.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationCurrentContext;
        [self presentViewController:initialVC animated:YES completion:nil];
}

-(IBAction)backDiffStoryboard:(id)sender{
UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main_iPhone" bundle:nil];
    UIViewController *initialVC = [storyboard instantiateInitialViewController];
    initialVC.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationCurrentContext;
    [self presentViewController:initialVC animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```